# Figure out used swap from command line?

Tags: command-line, activity-monitor, virtual-memory

When looking at the Activity Monitor it says that I am using 459.5MB of swap.

[I would like to figure this number out from the command line.](https://github.com/walles/px/issues/80)

I have been able to duplicate all the other memory numbers presented by the Activity Monitor using `vm_stat`, but now I want swap usage as well.

Help?

[image: Activity Monitor, swap file usage 459.5MB]

Comment: Is the "private MemRegions" shown by `top` the swap ? the value is the same on my Mac..

Comment: Nope. I have `136M private`  according to `top`, and 459,5MB swap usage according to the Activity Monitor.

Comment: What do you see for swapins/swapouts in `vm_stat`?  I've double checked `top` and `vm_stat` and like @anki both agree with what's in Activity Monitor.  Have you tried killing Activity Monitor and restarting it?

Comment: For context, I asked because I wanted to ptop (https://github.com/walles/px) and bubblemon (https://walles.github.io/bubblemon/) output to match the Activity monitor. And thanks to @jksoegaard now they do!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the current swap usage on the command line by running the following command:

```
sysctl vm.swapusage
```

It will output something similar to:

```
vm.swapusage: total = 4096.00M  used = 2743.50M  free = 1352.50M  (encrypted)
```

The number in "used" should correspond with the number you've circled in Activity Monitor.

Comment: Any chance you also know if the unit is always `M`? Not part of the original question, I know, but since I want to machine parse the result I do want to know.

Comment: Figured it out, answer is "yes", found source code at: https://opensource.apple.com/source/system_cmds/system_cmds-496/sysctl.tproj/sysctl.c.auto.html